# WEB API stored procedure call one at the time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Here is a problem I am facing: from WebAPI I need to return a piece of work received from DB by calling a stored procedure.

Every call to WebAPI should receive its own piece of work, how can I make sure that two calls to WebAPI won't execute the stored procedure call simultaneously and won't receive the same piece?

1. Should I lock the table from the stored procedure before searching for next piece?
2. If I'll use lock on stored procedure call from WebAPI, does that lock work on application level or on session level?

Anything else I can do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Read Remus Rusanu's excellent article [Using tables as queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) which explains in great detail what to do (in SQL Server) to use tables like queues - exactly what you want. And good heavens **NO**, do **NOT** lock the whole table just for that!!

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong; each api call will be having some kinda identifier to fetch the rrquired item from database, is it?

Comment: @Developer No caller won't have an identifier, caller simply asking give me next piece to work on and it's service responsibility to mark given piece as being worked on in DB,  the question is how to prevent the same piece being given twice if two callers managed to  call service simultaneously. As I can see its a usual racing conditions in multithreading application and in regular application would be solved by applying the lock on store proc call so only one process can utilize the store proc and receive a piece,  my problem that I am not sure how it works in Web api.

Comment: Okay. Im just assuming your stored proc logic -  you read a data from database and update a flag for that item to mark it as read in stored proc so that next stored proc execution could pick the next open work item. Is that right? If this is the case, would wrapping the entire stuff in transaction with the required isolation scope work for you?

Comment: @Developer yes thats a correct assumption prior to returning the item store proc marks item as distributed so next run will grab following item and yes wrapping in transaction would do the trick, but I am really interested how to achieve the same result from Web API code.

Comment: @user285682 - Web api will be called asynchronously, is it? So will it be a good idea to make it kinda synchronously. Or if you are looking to handle it in c#, may be instead of db transaction, may be you could try with ambient transactions.

Comment: @Developer the API can be called form Web Application (multiple users) so there is no way to control it on client side. Ambient transactions is good the question is when multiple requests are coming in are the being processed in one thread on server side or different threads, I would assume that different.

Comment: Yeah. Thats right, my bad. Seems like simple static object lock inside api action might work in this case.